# "Знаком" или "знакомым"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как лучше написать: "хотел бы быть знаком с ней" или "хотел бы быть знакомым с ней"?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Речь идет о личном знакомстве с кем-то**

Я бы написала так: ***Я хотел бы быть знаком с ней.***

Дело в том, что слово ***знакомый*** имеет два близких по смыслу значения:

**ЗНАКОМЫЙ,**  3. **Состоящий в знакомстве с кем-л.; лично известный.** З. человек. З. кому-л. художник, музыкант. Мы знакомы с детских лет. Ты знаком с соседом по купе? ◊ Шапочный знакомый.

Можно сказать:

***Я с ней знаком, мы с ней уже знакомы***. Здесь имеется в виду, что мы **представлены** друг другу, состоим в знакомстве (краткая форма).

***Мы хорошие знакомые, мы не друзья, а просто знакомые***. Речь идет о том, что мы **хорошо знаем** друг друга (полная форма).

Но вряд ли можно сказать: ***Я с ней знакомый, мы с ней знакомые***.

2) ***Речь идет о знании чего-либо*** (например, инструкции)

Тогда: ***хотел бы быть знакомым с ней (с инструкцией).*** Полная форма исключает тему личного знакомства с кем-то. Но эта фраза вряд ли часто используется.

3) Можно ли заменить фразу: ***хотел бы познакомиться*** (с кем-то или чем-то)?

**Нет, здесь другой смысл:** желание познакомиться относится к будущему, а в заданном предложении сослагательное (ирреальное) наклонение (хорошо бы уже быть знакомым в данный момент).

Comment: Проблема в том, что "знаком" характерно для настоящего времени (что подтверждает ваш пример), когда знакомство уже было. "Быть знаком" - звучит ужасно: *буду знаком завтра, скоро стану знаком, захочу быть знаком* (последнее вообще смешно, чего не сказать о "*если захочу быть знакомым с ней*") - в таких случаях корректно "познакомлюсь". Исключение: *должен быть знаком*.

Comment: Раньше говорили, не видели ничего ужасного. Чудак, ей-богу, ― говорил Виталин. ― Кстати или некстати, ― продолжал он, несколько помолчавши, ― хочешь ты быть знаком с этою женщиною? [А. А. Григорьев. Человек будущего (1845)]

Comment: А вот "я знакомый с ней"  в любом времени звучит ужасно, если уж  использовать ваши определения.

Comment: "Знакомый с ней" - ужасно звучит в настоящем и прошедшем. Но в будущем и с инфинитивом звучит явно лучше. "Быть знакомым" - нормально. Но это довольно спорно, так как люди так не говорят, стилистически оно и так и так звучит плохо. Стилистически правильно: познакомится - и по смыслу оно почти тоже самое (факт действия, а "знаком" - его результат). И вообще мне кажется, что сокращённая форма мало свойственна будущему времени и инфинитиву. Например: *он станет страшен* хуже, чем *он станет страшным*; *весной лес будет зелен* - плохо, а *весной лес будет зелёным* - хорошо. С "знаком" тоже самое.

Comment: Похоже, что стилистически оптимальный вариант без потерь - *хотел бы состоять в знакомстве с ней*.

Comment: Звучит или не звучит,  это всего лишь мнения. У вас есть источники, в которых на профессиональном уровне анализируется семантика  и стилистика форм "знаком и знакомый"? Во-первых, само  слово многозначное (есть знание чего-либо, а есть личное знакомство). Из вопроса вообще неясно, о чем речь.  Во-вторых, полная и краткая форма могут не совпадать по значению. Так что в этой теме не хватает ссылок на авторитетные книги по стилистике речи.

Comment: "Быть знакомым с ней" исключает вариант "быть её знакомым" - но смысл ведь тот же, только под другим углом. Знание чего-то - это знакомство с информацией (может, это переносное значение). Что насчёт краткой формы в будущем времени? Разделяете моё мнение?

Comment: Смысл разный. Быть представленным кому-то - это еще не значит числится в знакомых, то есть как-то общаться друг с другом.  А ваша "краткая" форма очень длинно и книжно звучит. Для разговорного варианта не подходит.

Comment: *Будет страшен, будет весел, будет силён, будет зелен* - проигрывают полной форме (с "знаком" та же история, хоть и спорная).

Comment: Речь идет о конкретном слове "знаком, знакомый", не стоит анализировать другие слова. Вы можете сказать: я с ней знакомый? Нет, не скажете, а то что о вас люди подумают. Значит,  полная форма для значения ЛИЧНОГО знакомства не подходит (в любых вариантах). Предлагаю на этом остановиться.

Answer (score 0):

Разница небольшая: одно прилагательное — краткая форма другого. Первый вариант (*знаком с ней*) предпочтителен; второй, также широко употребимый, мог бы быть слегка улучшен: «Хотел бы быть знакомым ей», или же более читабельное — «Хотел бы быть её знакомым», где слово З. станет существительным.

Answer (score -1):

Оба варианта стилистически не звучат. Но "*хотел бы быть **знакомым** с ней*" лучше.

Правильно: *хотел бы познакомиться с ней*.

Но это актуально для предположения:

*был бы **знаком*** - звучит гораздо лучше.

Answer (score -1):

Граматически оба варианта верны. 
На слух - второе лучше, чисто фонетически - нет скопления согласных.
Но вообще-то все может определить контекст.

"Познакомиться" - другой смысл. Применимо только к возможному в будущем событию.

***Когда у нас случилось ЧП, надо было действовать по должностной инструкции.*** Хотел бы я быть знакомым с ней"... - Тут прямая замена невозможна.